# Why doesn't Kerberos ("integrated authentication") work behind an AWS application elastic load balancer?

Tags: amazon-web-services, elastic-load-balancer

I have set up two elastic load balancers with two target groups in a similar configuration. One is a "network" ELB and the other is an "application" ELB. I've registered the SPN for each, set up IIS app pools appropriately, etc. The network ELB works but the application ELB makes the client browser present an authentication challenge prompt.

In both cases the server returns a `WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate` response initially.

Can someone explain to me what about the way Kerberos works makes these two scenarios different?

Comment: Maybe you could first explain, in a nutshell, what is the difference between these two Load Balancer types... And also, how the same SPN can be used against a *pool* of servers (regular Kerberos expects a single service type on a single, canonical DNS name, so I guess it's yet another Microsoft "feature").

Comment: (...or maybe IIS uses Kerberos only at the initial session handshake, then relies on a session token stored in a signed cookie -- standard trick in the Hadoop ecosystem; but then all servers must have a way to share the token)